# Is it possible to emulate a (windows) raid controller to recover a raid1 mirror?

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery, raid, emulation

So, Im gonna make a point to ask this question a couple of ways for the sake of wording, and how it might trigger a memory that someone might have experience.

Heres what I have:
1. Two hard drives 2TB each.

Heres what I did: 
1. Activated Raid0 striped → fakeraid via bios (legacy controller MBR)
2. Later on, activated Raid1 Mirror → Other half of the drives.
3. Backed up raid1 (essential files) → to that second raid = the Raid1 Mirror.

This is where I broke it: (Semi sorta on purpose)
1. deleted one drive, knowing (somehow) I could ultimately restore via the mirror.
2. Installed ubuntu to that drive.
 
3. Attempted to use “Disk Utility” , “Gparted” and “partitionmanager” to mount it/save it or even read it.

Now im sure if I absolutely had to, I could throw the drives into raid, and rebuild the mirror...
But is there a way for me to:
1. mount
2. read
3. emulate a full controller (by creating a 1GB Virtual image, and raiding it with the physical drive)
4. Emulate the FS (Mount it without)

Thanks in advance for any information you might have.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using DMRAID. Just follow this instructions: [Mounting FakeRAID](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions#Mounting_Fakeraid)

Please note, that fake raid controller are just like software raids. Linux will show you both hard drives even they are in raid mode.

But, I think it would be more safe to mount the hard drive with Windows and creating a backup. Using DMRaid could break your file system. You should also avoid using dynamic Windows volumes. If there is no license/installation media for Windows anymore you can download the Evaluation Version of Windows 2008 R2 Server: [Windows 2008 R2 Evaluation Version](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11093)

The best way for changing a operating system is to backup a raid on a extra device and rebuild the raid after installing the new operating system.

Comment: ill burn a Windows 7 Lite disk, install to an extra sata 20Gb, and install on it as IDE with the raid started.