# Will an Ubuntu Live USB be Able to Access a Windows RAID 10?

Tags: raid, data-recovery

My Windows will not boot, so I want to recover the files and reinstall. I've tried two different version of Linux (an old Ubuntu 7.10 disc and a Puppy Linux boot USB), but neither appears to be able to see the RAID 10 to mount it. If I create a boot USB with the current distro, will I be able to mount the RAID and transfer to an external? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to emulate a (windows) raid controller to recover a raid1 mirror?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/199198/is-it-possible-to-emulate-a-windows-raid-controller-to-recover-a-raid1-mirror?rq=1)

Comment: The live installer does not have RAID drivers by default. I do not know if you need dmraid or mdadm RAID drivers. But you can install then and mount RAID using RAID commands. Version of gparted in installer does not work with RAID, I did think gparted was going to add some RAID capability but do not know current status. Best to use RAID tools you normally use for your RAID install. Is it BIOS based or "fakeRAID"?  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FakeRaidHowto

Answer (score 0):

**Try GParted partition editor**

I know that there are some live CD options, the new Ubuntu comes with GParted Partition editor, but if you don’t want to download the whole thing, you can just download the GParted partition editor live CD from http://gparted.org/livecd.php